# Filter dataframe rows according to max column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

---

I have this `df` dataframe:

```
        artist               track  class1  class2      class3
0   Portishead               Roads   0.98    0.02          0.0
1  Yo La Tengo     Our Way to Fall   0.14    0.86          0.0
2    Radiohead  Fake Plastic Trees   0.03    0.97          0.0
```

given these user inputs:

```
input_value = 0.8
input_class = 'class2'
```

I use the following code in reorder the dataframe according to class2 max value:

```
 for col in df.ix[:,'class1':'class3']:
     if col == input_class:
        reordered_df = df.iloc[(df[input_class] - input_value).argsort()]
```

like so:

```
1  Yo La Tengo     Our Way to Fall   0.14    0.86          0.0
2    Radiohead  Fake Plastic Trees   0.03    0.97          0.0
0   Portishead               Roads   0.98    0.02          0.0
```

however, I still need to satisfy one class condition , that is class2 value must be the highest **float** value in each **row**. in other words:

```
0   Portishead               Roads   0.98    0.02          0.0
```

should be discarted, because max value belongs to another class.

how do I insert this condition on the snippet above?

Comment: Your df and reorded_df do not have the same values. Please look again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `max` row-wise along the columns, compare to `class2`, and discard accordingly.

```
reordered_df
        artist               track  class1  class2  class3
1  Yo La Tengo     Our Way to Fall    0.14    0.86     0.0
2    Radiohead  Fake Plastic Trees    0.03    0.97     0.0
0   Portishead               Roads    0.98    0.02     0.0

reordered_df[reordered_df.max(1) == reordered_df.class2]
        artist               track  class1  class2  class3
1  Yo La Tengo     Our Way to Fall    0.14    0.86     0.0
2    Radiohead  Fake Plastic Trees    0.03    0.97     0.0
```

Comment: could you please edit your solution using the snippet above? I need to keep both dataframes: `df`and `reordered_df`

Comment: @outkast You don't need the for loop. Also, see edit.